# Number of all possible n tuples of integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that number of n-tuples of integers for each n is countable. Since countable union of countable sets is countable, set of all possible n tuples of integers for different values of n is countable. Cardinality of this set is different from cardinality of number of real numbers in interval (0,1) as number of digits in real numbers can be infinite but number of digits in integers is always finite even though it may be unbounded.
Proof that number of real numbers in (0,1) is notcountable can be constructed as follows:

Let L be list of all real numbers lying in (0,1). Represent each number on the list using binary representation. Let the first number on the list be represented as $0.b_{1,1}b_{1,2} \cdots$. Similarly $i_{th}$ number is given by $0.b_{i,1}b_{i,2}\cdots$. Thus, $j_{th}$ digit after decimal for $i_th$ number is given by $b_{i,j}$. We can construct a real number not on this list by inverting $i_{th}$ digit of $i_{th}$ number on list L. Thus we get a new number where each binary digit is obtained by inverting $b_n=0.b_{1,1}b_{2,2} \cdots b_{i,i}\cdots$. This number $b_n’$ obtained by inverting $b_n$ Is not on L. Thus cardinality of set (0,1) is not countable. (0,1) can be mapped to R using function $tan^{-1}(\pi(x-0.5))$

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: You have yet to prove the set of infinite sequences is not countable.

Comment: @WilliamElliot - they also have not proven the Reimann hypothesis. But since neither one is something that they were trying to prove, nor have made any use of in the proof they gave, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is close to correct, but there is a problem that you have not addressed.

Suppose the first number in your list is $0.1_2$, and that it so happens that for all $n > 1$, the $n^{th}$ number in the list has $0$ as its $n^{th}$ bit. The new number constructed by your algorithm is then
$$0.01111..._2$$
But, alas,
$$0.01111..._2 = 0.1_2$$
contradicting your claim that this number is not already in the list.

Binary is not a good choice for proving Cantor's theorem. This problem is easily avoided in any other base (don't allow $b-1$ to be the choice when using base $b$). But in binary, that trick does not work.